# How to determine whether a curve can be smoothly parametrized in C

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

When I was reading complex analysis, I saw the definition for integration of a smooth curve, but late in a theorem, the proof is trying to integrate a triangle directly without proving that it can be smoothly parametrized by a interval. How can we determine this in general? Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The triangle is essentially a disjoint union of
$3$ consecutive smooth curves ($i.e.$ the sides of the triangle) . You can read the first 2 - 3 paragraphs in the writeup attached below for more clarification.

https://complex-analysis.com/content/curves_in_the_complex_plane.html